# c# Regex to modify all matching hrefs

Tags: c#, regex

How can I replace

```
<a href="page">Text</a>
```

with

```
<a href="page.html">Text</a>
```

where `page` and `Text` can be any set of characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work. Note that I only capture whatever is inside href.

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(?<=<a[^>]*?\bhref\s*=\s*(['""]))(.*)(?=\1.*?>)", "$2.html");
```

And append the .html to it. You may wish to change it to your needs.

Edit : before flame wars begin. Yes it will work for your specific example not for all possible html in the internet.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't parse HTML with regular expressions. See the answer to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)  for details.

UPD: As TrueWill has pointed out, you might want to do the replace with Html Agility Pack. But in some special cases the regexp proposed by FailedDev will do, although I would slightly modify it to look like this: `@"(?<=<a\b[^>]*?\bhref\s*=\s*(['""]))(.*)(?=\1.*?>)"` (put a `\b` after the `<a` to exclude other tags starting with "a").

Comment: I'm not trying to parse the HTML, I'm trying to do a string replace in a html file.

Comment: One simple regex would be `<a.*?href="(.*)".*?>(.*?)</a>` to find the parts.

Comment: @Justin808 But to do it correctly, you actually need to parse the document. For example, you will probably want to ignore scripts and comments.

Comment: @Gebb is correct. Any changes to HTML, particularly those affecting only a specific context (such as in an HREF), involve parsing. Take a look at http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/